# Prove that $\overline{A\cap B \cap C}=\overline{A}\cup(\overline{B}-\overline{A})\cup \overline C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

How do you prove $\overline{A\cap B \cap C}=\overline{A}\cup(\overline{B}-\overline{A})\cup \overline C$?

The only thing that seems clear to me is by deMorgan the LHS breaks down to $(\overline A \cup \overline B \cup \overline C)$. I'm not sure how the subtraction in the RHS would simplify. Please let me know how you go about it in detailed steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you show that $\overline{A} \cup (\overline{B} - \overline{A}) = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove it in an equation but I see it makes sense in a venn diagram...

Comment: please let me know what theorem I should apply to get the result.

Comment: Try taking an $x$ in the LHS and showing it lies in the RHS and vice versa